# Could we have a site listing projects built with answers on SE sites?

Tags: feature-request, site-crossover

I build a lot of stuff with the help of answers I get on Stack Exchange sites. And I know lots of other people do too. (It's kinda the point I guess...)

It'd be great if there was a meta site that listed projects built with the help of stackexchange sites.

My idea is that projects would be posted and could reference as many answers as appropriate. These answers could (nay, should) be from a variety of sites. Each referenced answer should contain an explanation of the application of the information.

The answers could then have an automatic link added, which might give people context if they find an answer using google.

Spam would be more of an issue than with the regular Q&A side of the SE network, but I figure that the voting system should be enough

Comment: [See also...](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70380/what-do-people-think-of-a-stack-overflow-project-marketplace-similar-to-elance-co/71674#71674)